# In how many ways Rdistinct balls can be placed in M distinct cells?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

R is greater than M and all cells must contain balls.

Comment: this has answers already, look up "stars and bars"

Comment: @gt6989b:This is **not** "stars and bars", *distinct* balls , *distinct* cells, the duplicate marking needs to be removed.

Comment: Yes. Only "stars and bars method" is not enough

Comment: Try inclusion- exclusion. All possibilities - at least 1 cell empty + at least 2 cells empty - ... $= M^R  - \binom{M}1 (M-1)^R + \binom{M}2 (M-2)^R - ....$

Comment: You're welcome !

Comment: @Pritam my mistake, nominating for reopen

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem:

$$x_1+x_2+...+x_M=R$$

with $x_i \ge 1$ and then you can do $x_i=y_i+1$, and the equation became:

$$y_1+y_2+...+y_M=R-M$$

with $y_i \ge 0$.

If the balls are different we will have:

$$\frac{(R-M+M-1)!}{(M-1)!}=\frac{(R-1)!}{(M-1)!}$$

Comment: Sir i mentioned r distinct balls. This is the case when r balls are identical

Comment: you can use the same idea!

Comment: Please show me how...

Comment: is that clear now?

Comment: This will cause repeatation sir, the first M balls which will be placed in different cells are not fixed. I mean, which M balls in which cells respectively....

Comment: You have to understand how to solve the problem for identical balls, not only apply the formula. If you do, you will see that is enough don't discount  the repetition of the balls.

Comment: see this: https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/

Comment: Sir, I am just asking about that "R-M". That means you are eliminating some balls. And that balls are not fixed.

Comment: I'm just changing the problem to another one that accept empty boxes and $R-M$ balls, but the result is the same.

Comment: I agree the changed problem is right. But my point is, I dont know which "R-M" balls I am using (as the balls are distinct ) . Suppose I have 4 cell and 6 balls(numbered 1 to 6). At first I'll place 4 balls in each cell and then we'll do the star and bar problem with the remaining. But sir you can't just simply place 4 random ball in those cells.